# Can I do a TextBox Validation after an outclick event?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, html

I have a javascript restricted calendar on a textbox, which prevents the user from selecting any more than 2 months prior.  If the user manually enters the date and not select from the calendar, they can get past it.  How do I do a Validation on a outclick, or tab event to check my conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onblur.asp) event is what you are looking for.